# how to use serve static file with express and react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I have a project made with create-react-app and i would like to use it within express ( as i need some back end functionnality).

basically, my server render a blank page when i run it....
here is the code of my server:

```
    const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// An api endpoint that returns a short list of items
app.get('/api/getList', (req,res) => {
    var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
    res.json(list);
    console.log('Sent list of items');
});

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , 'public', 'index.html'));
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

if i enter the endpoint http://localhost:5000/api/getList, i can see the result, but when i want to display my react app for the other end point, the page is blank.

The react app use different Route and i also added a proxy in the package.json.

my server source file is at the root of the react app like the image.
[image]

Does someone has an idea why the react app doesnt show?

Thanks

Comment: did you build your react app? the output from cra will create a `build` folder

Comment: the public folder won't contain your react application as a static asset. it's there to be used during development, and when you build, its contents get copied into the build folder

Comment: no i didnt build yet.
let me try to build it and change the "public" to "build"

Comment: @azium thanks after built, it works. thank you for the explanation regarding the public folder

Answer (score 0):

You have two lines that are kind of doing the same thing:

```
// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Will serve your index.html file to `http://localhost:5000/index.html`

According to the Express documentation https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

And then it seems like you have the second route:

`app.get('*'`, is formatted incorrectly.

It would need to be `app.get('/*'`.

If you aren't directing the user to multiple routes then it might be better to just use the root, `app.get('/',` rather than trying to catch all routes.

Comment: Hi,
if i use just  app.get('/')
i cant go to the other route, thats why i used app.get('*')